# cakephp 3 - format number input field

Tags: cakephp, view, formatting, decimal

I've an input form in my view like this :

```
$this->Form->input( 'shipping_amount' );
```

The corresponding matching field is defined as decimal(10,3) so it is displayed using a number html tag.

Depending upon the value, it shows none, 1, 2 or 3 decimals.

Is there a way to force always 2 decimal places from the view ?

Thanks.
Regards.
Facundo.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->Form->input( 'shipping_amount',['type'=>'text']);
```

And need little jacascirpt, if "#shipping-amount" is the id of your input field

```
$("#shipping-amount").on('blur change' , function() {       
   $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2))
}).trigger('blur');
```